# Prove ${2}^{n}\cdot(2m+1)-1 $ is invertible

Tags: calculus

Prove that the function ${2}^{n}\cdot(2m+1)-1$ from $\Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ is invertible

I know that a function to be invertible must be injective and surjective, I am not sure how to calculate this since in this case I need a pair $(x,y)$ since the function comes from ${\Bbb{N}}^{2}$.

Comment: Your function has only one variable $n$, but you say it comes from $\Bbb {N \times N}$.  Please check.  Maybe it is supposed to be $2^x(2y+1)-1$.  Also, do you include $0$ in $\Bbb N$?  Some do, some do not.

Comment: I imagine that you mean $2^n(2m+1)$? And also that for you $0 \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: yes I did a mistake, I updated the question, I am not sure if 0 is included, I do not have this information. Is it possible to do that without knowing it?

Comment: Yes, it is always(!) required to know the basic definitions of the objects you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $0\in \mathbb{N}$ so that even numbers lie in the image.

To show that it is surjective:

Every number $z \in \mathbb{N}$ with $z \neq 0$ has a unique decomposition into primes: $z=2^a3^b5^c...$, since all primes except 2 are odd and products of odd numbers are odd, $z$ can be written as $z=2^a \cdot x$ where $x$ is an odd number.

Now every odd number can be written as $2n+1$ for some $n$ (here the convention $0  \in \mathbb{N}$ must be taken to get $1$), so $z=2^a (2n+1)$ for some $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The function you are looking at is $2^m(2n+1)-1$, and if we can get any $z\neq 0$ to be of the form $z=2^m(2n+1)$, then we can get any number (including $0$) to be of the form $2^m(2n+1)-1$.

To show that it is injective:

It is less of a hassle to show that $2^m(2n+1)$ is an injective function.

Suppose you have $z=2^{m_1}(2n_1+1)=2^{m_2}(2n_2+1)$ for some $z\neq 0$,  since $2n_1+1$ and $2n_2+1$ are odd numbers, the exponent of the $2$ in the prime decomposition of $z$ must be the same as $m_1$ and $m_2$, especially $m_1=m_2$.

Dividing $2^{-m_1}$, you get $2n_1+1=2n_2+1$ which implies $n_1=n_2$.

Comment: So I did one example that was : $2^m.(2^n+1)-1=59$ which is $2^m.(2^n+1)=60$ which is $2^m.(2^n+1)=2.2.3.5$ after that I do not know how to continue, I did this because it was easier to be with an example. but I am not sure if it is correct

Comment: @user290335 You have a typo, the function is not $2^m(2^n+1)-1$ but $2^m(2n+1)-1$. In this case taking $m=2$ and $2n+1=3\cdot5$ or $n=7$ gives $2^2(2\cdot7+1)-1=4\cdot15-1=59$.

Comment: yes I am sorry. I did a mistake. and I cannot edit it more than 5 times

Comment: so if I do it like this it is enough to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Add $1$ and show that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \ni (m,n) \mapsto 2^m \cdot (2n+1) \in \{1,2,\ldots \}$ is bijective. Indeed, every number in $\in \{1,2,\ldots \}$ is uniquely a product between a power of $2$ and an odd number, and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ parametrizes pairs (power of $2$, odd number) by
$(m,n) \simeq (2^m, 2n+1)$. For instance, the inverse of $2016$ is obtained as follows: $2016= 2\cdot 1008 = 2^2 \cdot 504 = 2^3 \cdot 252= 2^4 \cdot 126 = 2^5 \cdot 63$. Note that $63 = 2 \cdot 31 + 1$. Hence $(5, 31) \mapsto 2016$.